# Arrhenius equation - Proper Interpretation of Activation Energy term

Tags: physical-chemistry, kinetics, energy

Consider the normal form of Arrhenius Equation:$$k=Ae^{-\frac {E_a}{RT}}$$

The term, $e^{-\frac {E_a}{RT}}$, is interpreted as the fraction of molecules having energy greater than Activation Energy.

**My question:** Isn't the term threshold energy better than activation energy?

---

Please provide a suitable interpretation of the terms involved.

Comment: In principle, the activation energy could have been called threshold energy. But nobody uses this word. It is a question of habit.

Comment: There is an answer here https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/139196/why-does-activation-energy-not-change-with-temperature-change/139222#139222

Comment: @Maurice Sir does that mean it is in actual sense Threshold Energy?