# Arrhenius Equation : Interpretation

Tags: physical-chemistry, kinetics, energy

Consider the relation:
$$E_{Activation}=E_{Threshold} - E_{Avg}$$

Here the $E_{Avg}$ refers to the Potential Energy of the reactants. Now in order of meet $E_{Threshold}$ , the molecules must have sufficient Kinetic Energy which is measured in terms of $E_{Activation}$.

Hence when we write Arrhenius equation:
$$k=Ae^{-\frac {E_{activation}}{RT}}$$

The term $exp(-E_{activation}/RT)$ means the number of molecules having Kinetic Energy greater than Activation Energy which coherently measures the minimum Kinetic Energy reactants need to have for reaction

---

Do my arguments make sense?

Comment: @Karl Sir I thought it was a famous relation from Potential Energy - Reaction Coordinate profile.

Comment: see the answer here https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/139196/why-does-activation-energy-not-change-with-temperature-change/139222#139222

Comment: @porphyrin Sir I have seen it. I just want to be reassured that whatever I have understood is correct. Please do the same if you feel my understanding is correct.

Comment: The activation energy is $E_T$ which you can split into parts if you want to to include a threshold plus average energy in the transition state, but not as you have written it above.

Comment: @porphyrin Sir in the post that you referred to me https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/139196/why-does-activation-energy-not-change-with-temperature-change/139222#139222 ,the same expression is in the question part as used as in my first expression. I have updated my expression accordingly.

Comment: That threshold energy makes no sense to me. The activation energy *is* the threshold. Please cite a source for this.