# Gibbs free energy of activation and activation energy

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, physical-chemistry, thermodynamics, kinetics

What the difference between Gibbs free energy of activation and activation energy

Comment: This question has the appropriate title for this related question, with the answers addressing both questions: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/15417/what-is-the-correct-definition-of-the-gibbs-free-energy-of-activation?rq=1
I don't know if that makes it a duplicate.

Comment: Activation energy is a broad term which may refer to the energy barrier of a reaction, whether calculated as enthalpy or Gibbs energy or whatever. The post linked by @KarstenTheis explains this pretty well.